# Run function on component display

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to run a function inside component every time user switch to this component. I tried to use ngOninit (run function inside only once) and other methods like ngOnComponentInit etc. but none of these worked for me.

Maybe I want to do this in a wrong way...

Please advice.

edit:

some example code.

home.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../auth/auth.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private auth: AuthService, private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    if(this.auth.token == null){
      this.router.navigate((['/']));
    }
  }

  someFunction(){
      console.log("ok");
      }
}
```

I want to run someFunction() everytime user switch to this component.

Comment: Provide your code.

Comment: @Kinduser  added some code

Comment: Try to move the logic from the `ngOnInit` function into the constructor.

Comment: That don't work. Code inside constructor run only once, on the very beginning. If I switch to another component and then go back, nothing happens.

Comment: Well, I've tried with onInit aswell as inside the constructor. The function gets called everytime I change the component in each option.

Comment: This is weird. If I put inside ngOnInit(){consoloe.log("ok")} I got one print inside console when I run app (home component is my main screen). After that when I click on another component and go back to home component, nothing print in console.

Comment: Yeah, this is weird. It shouldn't work this way.

Comment: By the way, you have too many braces in your navigate code. `navigate(['/']);`

Comment: I think it's right behaviour of ngOnInit though.

Comment: From angular website: ngOnInit is called right after the directive's data-bound properties have been checked for the first time, and before any of its children have been checked. It is invoked only once when the directive is instantiated.

Comment: @Maciejjy Yes, when component is instantiated, ngOnInit will run, if you route to a component that is not a child, and then back, ngOnInit should fire. If your "other component" is a child, then OnInit is not run again. Could you try and reproduce the issue in a plunker?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean `onFocus()`? This is what gets called when a user clicks on or tabs into a component.